# General SOCKS server failure with python tor but working from tor browser

Tags: python, tor, socks, torsocks

I would like to use tor from python to automate requests.
I made a test with a page to check IP and it works.

I then pointed to the site I want to, and apparently they avoid a tor endpoint because (see stack trace below) - but it works from tor browser.

Any better way to debug response of browser?
(e.g. connection refused)

Which things I am missing to query from python instead than from browser?

I am trying with something like:

```
socks.setdefaultproxy(socks.PROXY_TYPE_SOCKS5 , "127.0.0.1", 9150, True)
socket.socket = socks.socksocket

socks.wrapmodule(requests)
url = "myexample.com"
# r = requests.Session()
s = requests.get(url)
print s


    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 127, in urlopen
    return _opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 404, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 422, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 382, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1222, in https_open
    return self.do_open(httplib.HTTPSConnection, req)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1181, in do_open
    h.request(req.get_method(), req.get_selector(), req.data, headers)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 973, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 1007, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 969, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 829, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 791, in send
    self.connect()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 1172, in connect
    self.timeout, self.source_address)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 562, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/socks.py", line 747, in connect
    negotiate(self, dest_addr, dest_port)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/socks.py", line 419, in _negotiate_SOCKS5
    CONNECT, dest_addr)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/socks.py", line 494, in _SOCKS5_request
    raise SOCKS5Error("{0:#04x}: {1}".format(status, error))
socks.SOCKS5Error: 0x01: General SOCKS server failure
```

Comment: There are a few issues with that code, but do you know what version of Requests you are using?  If you have 2.10.0 or greater, don't try to monkey patch requests which may not work, instead use [proxies](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#socks)

Comment: Thanks @drew010, it worked I had also to upgrade to python3.

Answer (score 2):

Even though you use tor some website are looking for User Agent. Try to had User Agent header to your request. I had the same problem.

This worked for me

```
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import random
from fake_useragent import UserAgent
from torrequest import TorRequest
import time, socks, socket
from stem import Signal
from stem.control import Controller


ua = UserAgent()


with Controller.from_port(port = 9051) as controller:
    controller.authenticate(password = 'YourPasswordHere')
    socks.setdefaultproxy(socks.PROXY_TYPE_SOCKS5, "127.0.0.1", 9050)
    socket.socket = socks.socksocket   

    controller.signal(Signal.NEWNYM)
    if controller.is_newnym_available() == False:
        print("Waitting time for Tor to change IP: "+ str(controller.get_newnym_wait()) +" seconds")
        time.sleep(controller.get_newnym_wait())
    req = Request(url)
    req.add_header('User-Agent', ua.random)
    req_doc= urlopen(req)#.read().decode('utf8')
    print(req_doc)
```

Comment: Could you share an example that solved your problem?

Comment: Ok! Hey, I don't have to test your suggestion because it was an old project and should open it again, but I upvote on trust :) - it will be certainly useful also to other people landing on this question. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you. It is really usefull, i recently found out also. I had to merge couple solutions together :)